# Why does Japan spend more on Pharmaceutical R&D than the UK?

Tags: economy, healthcare, comparative-politics

Japan spends 13% of the world's total Pharma R&D while the UK spends 6% less ([source](https://www.abpi.org.uk/facts-and-figures/science-and-innovation/worldwide-pharmaceutical-company-rd-expenditure-by-country/)). Are there any reasons existing within the health system of Japan which allow this to happen?

Comment: This question is oddly specific. Can you add some background info on where your question is coming from? I think that might help get you better answers.

Answer (score 14):

The UK has a GDP of $2.91 trillion (PPP). Japan has a GDP of $5.42 trillion. ([source](https://www.investopedia.com/insights/worlds-top-economies/)).

The UK spends about 7% of the world's $1.36 trillion on pharma R&D, or about $95 billion. Japan spends 13%, or $177 billion. ([source](https://www.abpi.org.uk/facts-and-figures/science-and-innovation/worldwide-pharmaceutical-company-rd-expenditure-by-country/))

So the UK spends 3.26% of GDP on pharma research. Japan spends 3.26% on pharma research. There is no significant difference in spending between the countries.

This is in contrast to the USA, which spends more of its GDP on pharma research, and China which spends significantly less.

Comment: Also, R&D expenditure doesn't have a lot to do with the level of national healthcare. A lot of that R&D expenditure (in the US in particular) is by private companies that hope to turn up a profit globally from it.

Comment: I.e. R&D expenditure has more to do with comparative advantage and/or specialization than with national healthcare.

Comment: @Fizz: The same would be true of japanese companies, or companies in any country, doing research.  They would hope to develop successful products for a global marketplace.  It might be more informative to ask about research spending per capita.